# Docusign signing a document hosted on AWS S3

Tags: docusignapi

We plan to use Docusign for our eSignature requirements. Is there a way that I can pass an S3 presigned URL of a pdf file in docusign envelope and that is used by docusign for signing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. Your software will need to download the pdf from S3 and then upload it to the DocuSign platform. DocuSign does not fetch PDF files for you.

The good news is that this type of app is trivial. Many languages and stacks make it easy to use a URL reference as if it was a local file. Then just upload the content to DocuSign.